# Groovy/Java split string on parentheses "("

Tags: java, groovy, escaping, pattern-matching

I am trying to perform a split similar the following:

```
println "Hello World(1)".split("W");
```

Output:

```
[Hello , orld(1)]
```

I want to perform this split:

```
println "Hello World(1)".split("(");
```

But I see:

```
Caught: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 1 (
```

Is there a way I can escape this parentheses? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to escape it like this `\\(`

Comment: that escape does not work @ant

Comment: sorry double back slash

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
println "Hello World(1)".split("\\(");
```

Answer (score 25):

The `split` method takes a regular expression pattern.

If you want to split on "just a regular string" you can use `Pattern.quote` to quote the string first:

```
println "Hello World(1)".split(Pattern.quote("("))
```

Comment: or you can split on `"\\("`, which first escapes `\\(` to `\(`, then the regex engine escapes `\(` to a literal parentheses

Comment: This is interesting.. I did not think about using Pattern.quote() in this circumstance. Good answer Jon

Comment: @jedyobidan: Well that's exactly what `Pattern.quote` will do - it just means you don't need to do it manually...

Answer (score 2):

Since *split* just accept regex, you have to pass to it as an escaped character. For this, you must append a backslash in front of it

```
\(
```

But above has a compile error because it is parsed as a valid escaped character such as:

```
\t Tab
\n New Line or Line Feed
\r Carriage Return
```

So, you must pass a non meaning character (E.g. parenthesis) with 2 backslashes:

```
\\(
```

Finally:

```
println "Hello World(1)".split("\\(");
```

OR you can also do all things by java builtin function of class *Pattern* named *quote*:

```
println "Hello World(1)".split(Pattern.quote("("));
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to escape the bracket character properly

```
println "Hello World(1)".split("\\(")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a single escape when using groovy native regex syntax:

```
assert "Hello World(1)".split(/\(/) == ["Hello World", "1)"]
```