# How to search for a special character in java string?

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I am having some problem with searching for a special character "(".
I got a `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException exception has occurred`.
It might have  something  to do with "(" being treated as special character.
I am not very good with pattern expression.  Can someone help me properly search for the escape character?

```
   // I need to split the string at the "("

   String myString = "Room Temperature (C)";
   String splitList[] = myString.split ("(");   // i got an exception


   // I  tried this but got compile error           
   String splitList[] = myString.split ("\(");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you got an exception the first time is because [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a *regular expression* as argument, and `(` has a special meaning there, as you suggest. To avoid this, you need to escape it using a `\`, like you tried.

What you missed, is that you also need to escape your backslashes with an extra `\` in Java, meaning you need a total of two:

```
String splitList[] = myString.split ("\\(");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try one of these:

```
string.split("\\(");
string.split(Pattern.quote("("));
```

Since a string split takes a regular expression as an argument, you need to escape characters properly. See Jon Skeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15236141/1380918) on this here:

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the character via backslashes: `string.split("\\(");`

Answer (score 1):

`(` is one of regex [special](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) characters. To escape it you can use e.g.

- `split(Pattern.quote("("))`,
- `split("\\Q(\\E")`,
- `split("\\(")`,
- `split("[(]")`.